# Auto open Activity when notification is send without clicking on notification

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications, onesignal

Is it possible to perform some function in an app activity when the notification is sent, without the user clicking on the Notification bar?

Example: I have an onClick method which is needed to be called when Notification is sent.

Comment: What research have you done regarding notifications? IIRC, OneSignal uses FCM behind the scenes so there must be a lot of documentation available

Comment: NOPE .it shouldn't .it's out of user privacy and UI friendly and i am sure google won't let you do this.

Comment: you can use firebase push notification to achieve your functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes from notificationReceiver onReceive() method you can directly call startActivity like below

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityName.class);
        resultIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://"
                + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(resultIntent);
```

Comment: but when app is not open then it is not working